# Using "is" contraction for common nouns

Tags: grammar, american-english, syntax, contractions

I found this question in a grammar textbook while studying for an exam.
This is the sentence:

“Whatever the justifications/justification’s for your attitude…” 
Circle the correct answer.

The correct answer is apparently justifications and not justification’s but it still doesn’t make any sense to me, anyone know why?

Comment: How many are there?

Comment: Is the rest of the sentence not included in the question?

Answer (score 1):

"Whatever the justifications for your attitude" would be normal, if there are several justifications.

"Whatever the justification’s for your attitude" is technically correct, if you are treating "justification’s" as a contraction of "justification is".  However, when spoken, it is indistinguishable from "justifications".  So it would be misleading to use that contraction.

Comment: In normal US English that contraction in that context would rarely if ever be used.

Comment: Yes and in normal British English that contraction in that context would so clearly never be used, the question becomes why? Which parts don't make sense after which examples did you scrutinize, please?